# In Super Mario World what is the trick for getting 1ups on the vertical bonus levels?

Tags: super-mario-world

In Super Mario World for the SNES, getting 100 stars allows access to a bonus level with five vertical platforms, each with three coin boxes. If you hit the boxes in the right order the third box reveals a 1up. What is the pattern for this and is it the same for everytime you encounter this bonus level?

Comment: The 100 stars thing gives you access to a room with 9 blocks, 8 rotating around a middle one, where you try to get three symbols in a row, for up to 8 1-ups

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no pattern. The box that contains the 1up is assigned randomly to one of the three on that tier and doesn't change the location of other 1ups on that bonus level.

However, there is a method to con the boxes into being "the right one", be it a glitch or otherwise. This method involves hitting the corner of a box with your cape (while spin jumping), but without jumping too high and making it into the next section.

**Edit:** Here's a video of someone executing this method:

Comment: +1 as I always thought that hitting it from the side with your cape -was- the guaranteed way to accomplish this.

Comment: Small detail but if you do the first two with the cape you can just jump into the third one every time

Answer (score 4):

According to this video, you just need to time it so that you hit the block when the question mark is centered in the box. The order of the blocks doesn't matter.

Comment: The question mark is nowhere near centered at 0:48 or 0:57. It seems like it's just random...